# C Pointers: How is the following output genrated?

Tags: c, pointers

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

char *c[] = {"GeksQuiz", "MCQ", "TEST", "QUIZ"};
char **cp[] = {c+3, c+2, c+1, c};
char ***cpp = cp;

int main()
{
    printf("%s \n", **++cpp);
    printf("%s \n", *--*++cpp+3);
    printf("%s \n", *cpp[-2]);      // line 3
    printf("%s \n", cpp[-1][-1]);   // line 4
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
TEST 
sQuiz 
QUIZ 
MCQ
```

Can someone please explain the output of line 3 and line 4?
I understand the output of the first two **printf** statements but line 3 and 4 blew my mind!

Comment: Side note: Write code like this more than once and odds are your coworkers will start plotting your exit from the company.

Comment: It's amazing what people will put in code because they think it will be faster. One day I stumbled across `x=x<<3+x+x;` I checked the math with pen and paper to make sure it was `x*=10;` and replaced it. When I found more like that, I scheduled an intervention because the kid was smart and it would have sucked to lose them.

Comment: @user4581301 such code *used to be* written when compilers were dumber, AFAIK.

Comment: @user253751 Understood. I had to do similar things on jobs where compiler optimization was forbidden. This case was at most five years ago with a new programmer fresh from school and a mandated g++ -O2. Turns out they just didn't trust the compiler to optimize the code. I showed them how to dump the assembled output so they could inspect it, and then recommended they not spend much time on tuning unless the program needed it. Perfect code is nice, but there are schedules to meet.

Answer (score 3):

`cpp` points to `cp` at the begin. It gets incremented twice in the first 2 lines, therefore it points to `cp + 2` at line 3. `(cp + 2)[-2]` is `*(cp + 2 - 2)`, which is `*cp`. `*cp` is `c+3`, which is with another `*` `"QUIZ"`.

`cpp` still points to `cp + 2` at line 4, with index `-1` will give `cp[1]`, which is `c+2`, again index `-1` gives `c[1]`, which is `"MCQ"`.

Answer (score 1):

Array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So in this declaration

```
char ***cpp = cp;
```

the array designator `cp` is converted to pointer to its first element that is defined by the expression `c+3`.

In the calls of printf the pointer `cpp` is incremented twice. The first time in this call

```
printf("%s \n", **++cpp);
```

and the second time in this call

```
printf("%s \n", *--*++cpp+3);
```

So inside the first call the pointer cpp after increment points to the second element of the array `cp` that is it points to the element initialized like `c+2`. So dereferencing the pointer we get the pointer to the string literal `"TEST"` that is outputted.

In the second call the pointer `cpp` is again incremented. So its points to the element of the array `cp` that is defined by the expression `c + 1`. Deereferencing this pointer `*++cpp` we get a pointer with the value `c + 1`. Decrementing the value `--*++cpp` we get a pointer with the value `c` that is a pointer that points to the first element of the array `c`. Dereferencing the pointer we get the pointer to the first element of the string literal `"GeksQuiz"`. Now adding the number 4 to the pointer `*--*++cpp+3`  we get a pointer that points to the fourth character of the string literal. So in this call of printf the output is `"sQuiz"`

As it was pointed out the pointer cpp points now to the third element of the array cp after incrementing it two times. So the expression `cpp[-2]` yields the first element of attay `cp` that has the value `c+3`. SO the literal `"QUIZ"` is outputted in this call

```
printf("%s \n", *cpp[-2]);      // line 3
```

This expression `cpp[-1]`  yields the second element of the array `cp` that is initialized like `c+2`. Using the expression `cpp[-1][-1]` we get a pointer to to the second element of the array c that is to the string literal  `"MCQ"` that is outputted in this call

```
printf("%s \n", cpp[-1][-1]);   // line 4
```